# How can i generate a json script out of these 3 Tables while using a php script

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to join these 3 tables once in one query , after doing that i use php to come out with a json file in the web browser(localhost)

Below is the decription of the pictures;
1.Is the `Movie Table`
2 Is the `Cinemax Table`
3. Is the `Showtime Table`

[image: This is my Movies Table in the picture below]

[image: This is my Cinemax Table]

[image: This is my ShowTime Table]

Below is the output of JSON script i want with those fields to output from the php script after joining all the 3 tables in Mysql.

```
[{
"Cinemax":"Ntinda", "Contacts":"0704594180","Movie":[{"MovieName":"Zootopia", "ShowTime":[
{"Monday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m", 
"Tuesday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
"Wednesday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
"Thursday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
"Friday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
"Saturday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
"Sunday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m"},
{"MovieName":"Ice Age 3", "ShowTime":[
{"Monday":"4:30 p.m , 6:40 p.m", 
"Tuesday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
"Wednesday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
"Thursday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
"Friday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
"Saturday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
"Sunday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m"}

], "Synopsis:"Its really a nice animation movie", "photo":"zootopia.jpg",
"others":"Animation"},

"Cinemax":"Kisementi", "Contacts":"0700304850","Movie":[{"MovieName":"Zootopia","ShowTime":[
{"Monday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m", 
"Tuesday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
"Wednesday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
"Thursday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
"Friday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
"Saturday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
"Sunday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m"},
{"MovieName":"Ice Age 3", "ShowTime":[
{"Monday":"4:30 p.m , 6:40 p.m", 
"Tuesday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
"Wednesday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
"Thursday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
"Friday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
"Saturday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m",
"Sunday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m"}

], "Synopsis:"Its really a nice animation movie", "photo":"zootopia.jpg",
"others":"Animation"}

}]
```

This is my current Php script, so how can i try to get that format of Json

```
<?php  
$username="root";  
$password="namungoona";  
$hostname = "localhost";  
//connection string with database  
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)  
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");  
echo "";  
// connect with database  
$selected = mysql_select_db("UgandaEntertainment",$dbhandle)  
or die("Could not select examples");  
//query fire  
$result = mysql_query("select Movie.MovieName,

Movie.Synopsis,
Movie.photo,
Movie.Others,
Cinemax.CinemaName,
Cinemax.Longitude,
Cinemax.Latitude,
Cinemax.Contact,
Cinemax.CinemaxPhoto,
ShowTime.Monday,
ShowTime.Tuesday,
ShowTime.Wednesday,
ShowTime.Thursday,
ShowTime.Friday,
ShowTime.Saturday,
ShowTime.Sunday,
Actor.ActorsName,
Actor.ActorsPhoto

from Movie
inner join Cinemax
ON Movie.CinemaxId=Cinemax.CinemaxId
inner join ShowTime
ON Movie.MovieId=ShowTime.MovieId

inner join Actor
ON  Movie.MovieId=Actor.MovieId

;


");  
$json_response = array();  
// fetch data in array format  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {  
// Fetch data of Fname Column and store in array of row_array  
$row_array['MovieName'] = $row['MovieName']; 
$row_array['Synopsis'] = $row['Synopsis']; 
$row_array['Others'] = $row['Others']; 
$row_array['CinemaName'] = $row['CinemaName'];
$row_array['photo'] = $row['photo']; 
$row_array['CinemaxPhoto'] = $row['CinemaxPhoto'];
$row_array['Longitude'] = $row['Longitude'];
$row_array['Latitude'] = $row['Latitude'];
$row_array['Contact'] = $row['Contact'];
$row_array['Monday'] = $row['Monday'];
$row_array['Tuesday'] = $row['Tuesday'];
$row_array['Wednesday'] = $row['Wednesday'];
$row_array['Thursday'] = $row['Thursday'];
$row_array['Friday'] = $row['Friday'];
$row_array['Saturday'] = $row['Saturday'];
$row_array['Sunday'] = $row['Sunday'];
$row_array['ActorsName'] = $row['ActorsName'];
$row_array['ActorsPhoto'] = $row['ActorsPhoto'];



//push the values in the array  
array_push($json_response,$row_array);  
}  
//  
echo json_encode($json_response);  
?>
```

This is my new OutPut For JSON

```
[{"Cinemax":"Ntinda Cinemax","Contacts":"0704594180","Movie":[{"MovieName":"Ice Age 3","ShowTime":{"Monday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m","Tuesday":"1:30 pm , 3:40 p.m","Wednesday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Thursday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Friday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Saturday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Sunday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m"},"Synopsis":"Manny, Diego and sid","photo":"ice_age_3.jpg","others":"cinema and comedy"}]},{"Cinemax":"Ntinda Cinemax","Contacts":"0704594180","Movie":[{"MovieName":"Ice Age 3","ShowTime":{"Monday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m","Tuesday":"1:30 pm , 3:40 p.m","Wednesday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Thursday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Friday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Saturday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Sunday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m"},"Synopsis":"Manny, Diego and sid","photo":"ice_age_3.jpg","others":"cinema and comedy"}]},{"Cinemax":"Ntinda Cinemax","Contacts":"0704594180","Movie":[{"MovieName":"Ice Age 3","ShowTime":{"Monday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m","Tuesday":"1:30 pm , 3:40 p.m","Wednesday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Thursday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Friday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Saturday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Sunday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m"},"Synopsis":"Manny, Diego and sid","photo":"ice_age_3.jpg","others":"cinema and comedy"}]}]
```

Me I want something like this , without a repaetition of the Same Cinemax

```
[{"Cinemax":"Ntinda Cinemax","Contacts":"0704594180",
"Movie":[{"MovieName":"Zootopia","ShowTime":{"Monday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m","Tuesday":"1:30 pm , 3:40 p.m","Wednesday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Thursday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Friday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Saturday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Sunday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m"},"Synopsis":"Manny, Diego and sid","photo":"ice_age_3.jpg","others":"cinema and comedy"}]},{"Cinemax":"Ntinda Cinemax","Contacts":"0704594180","Movie":[{"MovieName":"Ice Age 3","ShowTime":{"Monday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m","Tuesday":"1:30 pm , 3:40 p.m","Wednesday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Thursday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Friday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Saturday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Sunday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m"},"Synopsis":"Manny, Diego and sid","photo":"ice_age_3.jpg","others":"cinema and comedy"}]},{"Cinemax":"Ntinda Cinemax","Contacts":"0704594180","Movie":[{"MovieName":"Ice Age 3","ShowTime":{"Monday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m","Tuesday":"1:30 pm , 3:40 p.m","Wednesday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Thursday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Friday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Saturday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Sunday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m"},
"Synopsis":"Manny, Diego and sid","photo":"ice_age_3.jpg","others":"cinema and comedy"},{"MovieName":"Ice Age 3","ShowTime":{"Monday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m","Tuesday":"1:30 pm , 3:40 p.m","Wednesday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Thursday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Friday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Saturday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Sunday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m"},"Synopsis":"Manny, Diego and sid","photo":"ice_age_3.jpg","others":"cinema and comedy"}]},{"Cinemax":"Ntinda Cinemax","Contacts":"0704594180","Movie":[{"MovieName":"Ice Age 3","ShowTime":{"Monday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m","Tuesday":"1:30 pm , 3:40 p.m","Wednesday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Thursday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Friday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Saturday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Sunday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m"},"Synopsis":"Manny, Diego and sid","photo":"ice_age_3.jpg","others":"cinema and comedy"}]},{"Cinemax":"Ntinda Cinemax","Contacts":"0704594180","Movie":[{"MovieName":"Ice Age 3","ShowTime":{"Monday":"1:30 p.m , 3:40 p.m","Tuesday":"1:30 pm , 3:40 p.m","Wednesday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Thursday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Friday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Saturday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m","Sunday":"1:30 p.m., 3:40 p.m"},
"Synopsis":"Manny, Diego and sid","photo":"ice_age_3.jpg","others":"cinema and comedy"}]}]
```

**This one is Out Put Currently**

```
string(440) "[{"Cinemax":null,"Contacts":null,"Movie":[{"CinemaxId":null,"MovieName":null,"ShowTime":{"Monday":null,"Tuesday":null,"Wednesday":null,"Thursday":null,"Friday":null,"Saturday":null,"Sunday":null},"Synopsis":null,"photo":null,"others":null},{"CinemaxId":null,"MovieName":null,"ShowTime":{"Monday":null,"Tuesday":null,"Wednesday":null,"Thursday":null,"Friday":null,"Saturday":null,"Sunday":null},"Synopsis":null,"photo":null,"others":null}]}]"
```

Comment: Does your MYSQL querry returns what you want ?

Comment: Yes it returns what i want , but am looking for a way to avoid duplicates in it via php , so that it produces the JSON i have posted @ Christophvh

Comment: I want each CinemaName to appear once , but all with its relevant information, without neglecting any, like that nested JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$json_response = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $movieArray = array(
        "MovieName" => $row['MovieName'],
        "ShowTime" => array(
            "Monday" => $row['Monday'],
            "Tuesday" => $row['Tuesday'],
            "Wednesday" => $row['Wednesday'],
            "Thursday" => $row['Thursday'],
            "Friday" => $row['Friday'],
            "Saturday" => $row['Saturday'],
            "Sunday" => $row['Sunday']
        ),
        "Synopsis" => $row['Synopsis'], 
        "photo" => $row['photo'], 
        "others" => $row['Others']
    );
    $cinema = array(
        "Cinemax" => $row['CinemaName'],
        "Contacts" => $row['Contact'],
        "Movie" => array($movieArray)
    );
    $key = array_search($row['CinemaName'], array_column($json_response, 'Cinemax'));
    if($key !== false)
    {
        $json_response[$key]["Movie"][] = $movieArray;
    } else {
        $json_response[]= $cinema;
    }
}
var_dump(json_encode($json_response));
```

---

Ok, i will try to explain what i did:
First you have the input witch is an array:

```
$row['MovieName'] = 'Suicide Squad';
$row['Synopsis'] = "Bla bla tests";
$row['Others'] = "others";
$row['CinemaName'] = "CinemaRX";
$row['photo'] = 'test.jpg';
$row['CinemaxPhoto'] = 'cinemax.jpg';
$row['Longitude'] = '123';
$row['Latitude'] = '321';
$row['Contact'] = '0731565131';
$row['Monday'] = '10:00';
$row['Tuesday'] = '11:00';
$row['Wednesday'] = '12:00';
$row['Thursday'] = '13:00';
$row['Friday'] = '14:00';
$row['Saturday'] = '15:00';
$row['Sunday'] = '16:00';
$row['ActorsName'] = "Tom";
$row['ActorsPhoto'] = "tom.jpg";
```

I added some random data:

So you have multiple arrays like this coming from the database, so i will put my method in a for() for testing purpose:

```
    $json_response = array();
    for($i = 0; $i<2; $i++) {
        $movieArray = array(
            "MovieName" => $row['MovieName'],
            "ShowTime" => array(
                "Monday" => $row['Monday'],
                "Tuesday" => $row['Tuesday'],
                "Wednesday" => $row['Wednesday'],
                "Thursday" => $row['Thursday'],
                "Friday" => $row['Friday'],
                "Saturday" => $row['Saturday'],
                "Sunday" => $row['Sunday']
            ),
            "Synopsis" => $row['Synopsis'],
            "photo" => $row['photo'],
            "others" => $row['Others']
        );
        $details = array(
            "Cinemax" => $row['CinemaName'],
            "Contacts" => $row['Contact'],
            "Movie" => array($movieArray)
        );

//here you check if there is already another entry with the cinema name
        $key = array_search($row['CinemaName'], array_column($json_response, 'Cinemax'));
//if there is another entry with the same Cinema name you add the movie to that one.
        if($key !== false)
        {
            $json_response[$key]["Movie"][] = $movieArray;
        } else {
//if there isn't you add the cinema to the array 
            $json_response[]= $details;
        }
    }
    var_dump(json_encode($json_response));
```

This should work for any number of Cinema entries coming from the database.
Here is the actual output:

```
string(526) "[{"Cinemax":"CinemaRX","Contacts":"0731565131","Movie":[{"MovieName":"Suicide Squad","ShowTime":{"Monday":"10:00","Tuesday":"11:00","Wednesday":"12:00","Thursday":"13:00","Friday":"14:00","Saturday":"15:00","Sunday":"16:00"},"Synopsis":"Bla bla tests","photo":"test.jpg","others":"others"},{"MovieName":"Suicide Squad","ShowTime":{"Monday":"10:00","Tuesday":"11:00","Wednesday":"12:00","Thursday":"13:00","Friday":"14:00","Saturday":"15:00","Sunday":"16:00"},"Synopsis":"Bla bla tests","photo":"test.jpg","others":"others"}]}]"
```

The Movie Suicide Squat appears 2 times in the json, and the cinema name only one time.

Comment: Its has helped me @M.I but `Cinemax` object  is repeating itsself per the Movie. Me  i want the nested object `MovieName` only to just increase inside . This is my output from your answer please thanks @M.I

Comment: @kamanziabubakar Sorry, my bad, i used hardcoded Cinema name for testing and forgot to change it (The "CinemaRX" string should be the cinema name you are processing now). Please check now.

Comment: Please reply with the results if you haven't solve it by now.

Comment: Yes i have tried that @M.I, i have updated my post for the results am getting check them up , it has worked but the problem is , i just want  each cinemaName to appear once, coz am having many Cinemas in my databse , but when Object `Movie` which is nested plus the showTime to be  the only ones adding movies in per each cinema.

Comment: I have also tried to group by CinemaNames in Mysql , but Still it negelects some Movies, So i want to Group By CinemaNames , But Containing all the movies, Am not not getting your Output, check my Output  i have Editted my post

Comment: Pleae help me with that issue @M.I

Comment: Do you have an example where puts same CinemaName 2 times in the array? @kamanziabubakar

Comment: Yes please , Check Up in the post , i have edited it says **This is my new OutPut For JSON** Thats the example @M.I

Comment: Did you used the method after i corrected it ? I added some explanation on how it works. @kamanziabubakar

Comment: Yes  , i j used what you sent to me , but it gives different Output, please help me out with this bro @M.I, the CinemaNames are repeating themselves. I want Each CinemaName to Appear Once

Comment: I don't know how i can help you. Can you check the data form the db, from what i see you have same data added to the json multiple times. Did you completely replaced your method with the one from the answer?

Comment: put a var_dump() on: $key = array_search($row['CinemaName'], array_column($json_response, 'Cinemax')); And say what it returns.

Comment: Hey i Used `for()` method , but why are all fields bringing null , also please show how to place `var_dump()`, but we are near the answer. I think if that null goes it will be working well @M.I

Comment: Hey check my Output its title is **This one is Out Put Currently**

Comment: You don't have to use for() i used it for the example...Keep the while loop.  just put the $key in var_dump: var_dump($key). after the row  $key = array_search($row['CinemaName'], array_column($json_response, 'Cinemax')); in the method.